# In CMake for CUDA developent, how can I control gencode options?

Tags: cmake, cuda, cmakelists-options

I am configuring the project using CMakeLists.txt
generated nvcc compile options for gencode,
it contains almost all the arch options like the below.

```
-gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -gencode arch=compute_70,code=sm_70 -gencode arch=compute_75,code=sm_75 -gencode arch=compute_80,code=sm_80 -gencode arch=compute_86,code=sm_86 -gencode arch=compute_90,code=sm_90 -gencode arch=compute_90,code=compute_90
```

I want only -gencode arch=compute_80,code=sm_80
How can I prevent adding other options?

My CMakeLists.txt is like the below

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18 FATAL_ERROR)

project(MyCudaProject LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

# Set the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

file(GLOB_RECURSE ALL_SOURCE_FILES "src/*.cpp" "src/*.cu")

enable_language(CUDA)
include_directories("${CMAKE_CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}")

include_directories(
    ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src"
)

add_executable(cuda_app ${ALL_SOURCE_FILES})

target_include_directories(cuda_app PRIVATE
    ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src"
)

target_link_libraries(cuda_app PRIVATE ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})

target_include_directories(cuda_app PRIVATE ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.24.1

I tried to force the CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS but it does not affect the compile options.
ex>
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-DONNX_NAMESPACE=onnx_c2 -gencode arch=compute_80,code=sm_80 -Xcudafe

I exected only -gencode arch=compute_80,code=sm_80.

Comment: This is what variable [CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES.html) and property [CUDA_ARCHITECTURES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CUDA_ARCHITECTURES.html) are intended for.